# JS if greater than condition not returning correct result

Tags: javascript

I'm testing some client-side validation on my site and I've run into a bit of a snag.

```
var budget = document.forms["jobSubmit"]["currency-field"].value; 
var price = budget.replace("$", "");


if (Number(price) >= 9999) {
    alert("Budgets have a maximum of 9999 US dollars.");
    return false;
} else {
alert(price);   
}

return false;
```

When I try to do a simple *greater than* condition on my price field, it doesn't return the proper result.

So in this situation, despite that I put in 11111, the greater than isn't working.

[image]

However, if I were to switch it to `< 10`, for example, it'll work just fine and all numbers under 10 will trigger the condition.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try some basic debugging. `Number(11,111)` is `11`

Comment: In your picture there's a comma in the middle of `11,111.00` which is an invalid number. You will need to remove the commas or else `Number("11,111.00")` will return `NaN`.

Comment: Ah, right. Figured it was something simple like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var budget = "$111,111" 
var price = budget.replace("$", "").replace(',','');


if (Number(price) >= 9999) {
    alert("Budgets have a maximum of 9999 US dollars.");
    //return false;
} else {
  alert(price);   
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind a dependency, the library "numeral.js" handles parsing of formatted numbers very well.

Comment: @cadmium, that might be but that is OP's concern whether to use such library or not.

Comment: Or remove all invalid characters at once: `budget.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")`

Comment: @4castle, yes we can do that. But I think `,` is allowed in amount. If other invalid characters are present we should consider that as invalid input...thanks.